# Understanding regex / preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I'm using some regex (that works), but don't actually understand what it's doing.  Being a scientist, I like to follow everything that I do!

The code is from this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/118886/889604

```
$mtime = filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file);
return preg_replace('{\\.([^./]+)$}', ".$mtime.\$1", $file);
```

This code takes a file name (e.g. `/files/style.css`), and adds in the file's `mtime` (e.g. `/files/styles.1256788634.css`).

So, I get that `^` and `$` symbols are the beginning and end of the string to match, and that the `./` matches any character any number of times (because of the `+`), but how does the `mtime` end up inbetween the file name and the extension?

Comment: `[^./]` doesn't match any character, rather it matches any character that is not ( `[^...]` ) a dot or a forward slash. Dot inside of a character class ( `[.]` ) is just a dot.

Comment: didn't know that curly braces can be regex delimiters. Apparently this is the only case where the starting and the closing delimiter can be different (any other non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character can be a delimiter, but it must be repeated to close the regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{` and `}` are used as delimiters and do not take part of the search pattern. 
`\\.`is describing a dot. The dot has to be escaped (thus the backslashes) because a un-escaped dot would describe the presence of any single character. The round brackets `( ... )` define a group that can be accessed via `$1` in the second `preg_replace` parameter. The content of this group consists of `[^./]+`, which means

> a positive quantity of (defined via the `+` after the set) any single character that is not (`^` in the beginning of a set means `not`) a dot `.` or a slash `/`.

The round brackets are followed by a `$` which describes the end of the line.

The expression will match the file extension of the path, like `.css`, while `css` will be the value of the group `$1`. Therefore, `.css` will be replaced with `.$mtime.css` where `$mtime` will be the value of the php variable.

Comment: So how is *only* the file extension matched? If I had a string like `/files.test/styles.gb.css` would the regex I'm using still work or is it looking for the only `.` in the string?

Comment: @ChrisW Because you have *anchored* the pattern using the `$`, the `.XXX` or whatever can only come at the end of the string in order for the regex to declare success. Without the `$` you would be telling the regex engine that the "extension" can occur anywhere within the target string; with the `$`, it can only come at the end of the string.

Comment: Yes - the expression only matches the part where it **exactly** matches. This expression matches the following part: `.` followed by a number of characters that are **not** dots or slashes, followed by the end of the line.

Comment: @KennethK - thanks, starting to get there I think! Final question (I think) - why does there need to be a double backslash? I thought a single one would escape a dot?

Comment: @ChrisW Partly due to PHP; partly due to regex. In PHP, backslashes inside of quoted strings must be escaped (i.e. preceded by a backslash) in order to prevent a compilation error. In regex, certain characters are special characters (like `^` and `$`). In order to have the regex engine treat special characters as not special you have to escape them (by using a preceding backslash). Since you want a literal backslash in your string for the regex, in PHP it must be written as a double backslash.

Answer (score 0):

The `mtime` ends up in the output due to PHP's string interpolation rules, that cause variable referenced inside of a double-quoted string to output the variable's value rather than the literal text of the variable name. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double (last sentence of section) for more information.

Comment: Oops - obviously bad phrasing on my part - I know how to reference vars in php, I just don't understand regex!

Answer (score 0):

All the regex pattern is doing is replacing the entire file extension `.css` and storing the extension without the period `css` into a capture by using the parentheses `([^./]+)`.  It then replaces the extension `.css` from the `$file` with a period, the value of `$mtime`, another period, and the captured extension from the regex `$1`.

And a note: The `^` does NOT mean the beginning of the string. When it is in a group like `[^./]` it is saying "match any character EXCEPT these ones"

I hope all that makes sense.

Edit:  It only matches the .css part of the $file because of the `\\.` which tells the regex to start at the first period found in the $file and then move on to do the capture.  It must be escaped with the `\\.` because it would otherwise act like a regex period which matches any character.

Comment: You might adjust your answer to indicate what causes the pattern to match only the extension. The `\.([^./]+)` in and of itself is not sufficient.

Comment: Oh right! That starts to explain a lot - but how does it know it only to match the .css part of the filename?